# How to fix 'IHasInputDevices is obsolete. Use the Actions or ActionsBuilder class to simulate mouse and keyboard input' warning with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, deprecation-warning

After upgrading the Selenium NuGet packages in our solution to version 3.141.0 (both Selenium.WebDriver and Selenium.Support), the IHasInputDevices interface now has a warning:

> 'IHasInputDevices' is obsolete. 'Use the Actions or ActionsBuilder class to simulate mouse and keyboard input.'

[image: Screenshot of deprecation warning in Visual Studio]

I created a utility class called `LazyWebDriver`, which implements the `IWebDriver`, `IHasInputDevices` and `IActionExecutor` interfaces. The `LazyWebDriver` class delays the instantiation of `ChromeDriver` until a member of `IWebDriver` gets accessed. This allows us to pass an IWebDriver object around and delay the appearance of the browser window, in case a test fails during the setup phase.

Code for the LazyWebDriver class:

```
public class LazyWebDriver : IWebDriver/*, IHasInputDevices*/, IActionExecutor
{
    private System.Func<IWebDriver> createDriver;
    private IWebDriver driver;

    private IWebDriver Driver
    {
        get
        {
            if (driver == null)
                driver = createDriver();

            return driver;
        }
    }

    public string Url
    {
        get => Driver.Url;
        set => Driver.Url = value;
    }

    public string Title => Driver.Title;

    public string PageSource => Driver.PageSource;

    public string CurrentWindowHandle => Driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

    public ReadOnlyCollection<string> WindowHandles => Driver.WindowHandles;

    public IKeyboard Keyboard => ((IHasInputDevices)Driver).Keyboard;

    public IMouse Mouse => ((IHasInputDevices)Driver).Mouse;

    public bool IsActionExecutor => ((IActionExecutor)Driver).IsActionExecutor;

    public LazyWebDriver(System.Func<IWebDriver> createDriver)
    {
        this.createDriver = createDriver;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        Driver.Close();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Driver.Dispose();
    }

    public IWebElement FindElement(By by)
    {
        return Driver.FindElement(by);
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElements(By by)
    {
        return Driver.FindElements(by);
    }

    public IOptions Manage()
    {
        return Driver.Manage();
    }

    public INavigation Navigate()
    {
        return Driver.Navigate();
    }

    public void Quit()
    {
        Driver.Quit();
    }

    public ITargetLocator SwitchTo()
    {
        return Driver.SwitchTo();
    }

    public void PerformActions(IList<ActionSequence> actionSequenceList)
    {
        ((IActionExecutor)Driver).PerformActions(actionSequenceList);
    }

    public void ResetInputState()
    {
        ((IActionExecutor)Driver).ResetInputState();
    }
}
```

The warning indicates to use the Actions or ActionBuilder class, so I removed the IHasInputDevices interface from the LazyWebDriver class, and attempted to use the Actions class:

```
[TestClass]
public class DeprecatedInterfaceTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        using (var driver = new LazyWebDriver(() => new ChromeDriver()))
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.stackoverflow.com");

            var link = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href='/teams/customers']"));
            var actions = new Actions(driver);

            actions = actions.MoveToElement(link);
            actions = actions.Click(link);
            actions.Perform();
        }
    }
}
```

The test failed with the following error message:

> Test method DeprecatedInterfaceTest.Test threw exception:
> System.ArgumentException: The IWebDriver object must implement or wrap a driver that implements IHasInputDevices.
> Parameter name: driver

The test fails at this line:

```
var actions = new Actions(driver);
```

I did some searching online, and I didn't find a way to eliminate the IHasInputDevices interface and use the Actions class as indicated in the obsolete warning. It also appears the ActionBuilder class is used to queue up a bunch of Actions objects.

**How can I eliminate the IHasInputDevices interface and still use the Actions class?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in 3.14 you can not eliminate the IHasInputDevices interface

Refer this [selenium-3.141.59/dotnet/src/webdriver/Interactions/Actions.cs#L68](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.141.59/dotnet/src/webdriver/Interactions/Actions.cs#L68) Its checking for IHasInputDevices . Even [RemoteWebdriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.141.59/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.cs#L64) in 3.14 implements IHasInputDevices so your LazyWebDriver must implement it .

```
IHasInputDevices inputDevicesDriver = GetDriverAs<IHasInputDevices>(driver);
```

This will check and throw the exception

```
public Actions(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            //this.driver = driver;
            IHasInputDevices inputDevicesDriver = GetDriverAs<IHasInputDevices>(driver);
            if (inputDevicesDriver == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The IWebDriver object must implement or wrap a driver that implements IHasInputDevices.", "driver");
            }

            IActionExecutor actionExecutor = GetDriverAs<IActionExecutor>(driver);
            if (actionExecutor == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The IWebDriver object must implement or wrap a driver that implements IActionExecutor.", "driver");
            }

            this.keyboard = inputDevicesDriver.Keyboard;
            this.mouse = inputDevicesDriver.Mouse;
            this.actionExecutor = actionExecutor;
        }
```

As in Selenium 4 . IHasInputDevices is removed . [ChangeLog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/trunk/dotnet/CHANGELOG)

```
 Removed IHasInputDevices and IHasTouchScreen and implementations. The Mouse,
   Keyboard, and TouchScreen implementations in the .NET bindings were never
   intended to be used by user code. Instead, users are expected to use the
   Actions and TouchActions classes or the ActionBuilder class to create
   complex interactions with pages being automated. This change reinforces that
   behavior, making it explicit.
```

If you implement LazyWebdriver in Selenium 4 then you won't be having this issue as IHasInputDevices is removed and Actions class only check for IActionExecutor . Refer [Actions.cs selenium-4.0.0-alpha-6](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-4.0.0-alpha-6/dotnet/src/webdriver/Interactions/Actions.cs#L58)

```
public Actions(IWebDriver driver)
{
    IActionExecutor actionExecutor = GetDriverAs<IActionExecutor>(driver);
    if (actionExecutor == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The IWebDriver object must implement or wrap a driver that implements IActionExecutor.", "driver");
    }

    this.actionExecutor = actionExecutor;
}
```

Comment: Ok, good. So nothing fancy. Just upgrade when 4.0 is released, and remove the silly interface from my LazyWebDriver class. Finally, an easy problem to solve. Thanks!