# Upgrade selenium 3 to selenium 4

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm upgrading selenium 3 to selenium 4, and I find that the Findsby interface is deprecated, the problem is that in my code is massively used, I have hundreds of tests that use Findsby... Changing it would take me many hours of work...
Is there any way to continue using Findsby in selenium 4?

This is an example of code that is not working now:

```
    [FindsBy(Using = "publisdate")]
    public WebElement publishDate;

    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName)]
    public IList<fieldElement> field;

    [FindsBySequence]
    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "groupby")]
    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "iconby")]
    public IList<WebElement> icons;
```

Thanks!

Comment: I did some research into this. Basically, the answer is "no", unless you want to rewrite this yourself. [How to fix 'IHasInputDevices is obsolete. Use the Actions or ActionsBuilder class to simulate mouse and keyboard input' warning with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63073549/3092298). The preferred method is using expression bodied members, which of course for you means rewriting a lot of code.

Comment: The [DotNetSeleniumExtras](https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras) NuGet package contains PageFactory, but as of today there is no owner of that repository. The code and NuGet package are still available, but nobody is maintaining it.

Comment: Thanks guys... So there's no solution for this? :(   It will be crazy to change all this code...

Comment: There is a solution, which is to use the DotNetSeleniumExtras package. The downside being that it is not currently supported by anyone. At this time, it is literally a copy-and-paste of the same code in the Selenium 3 project.